# C++, Pass a command line argument to makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I need to pass a command line argument which is a file name as a string to the program(main.cpp) in the makefile. I have seen most of the other post but don't understand how to implement them into my file. How should I proceed to do that? Thank you!

[main.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t97hb.png)

[Program structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqzHt.png)

makefile

```
OBJS    = main.o HashTable.o Book.o
SOURCE  = main.cpp HashTable.cpp Book.cpp
HEADER  = HashTable.h Book.h
OUT = book
CC   = g++
FLAGS    = -g -c -Wall -Wextra -std=c++1z

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS) -o $(OUT) $(LFLAGS)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) main.cpp

HashTable.o: HashTable.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) HashTable.cpp

Book.o: Book.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) Book.cpp

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OUT)
```

Comment: Your makefile doesn't run your program. You pass command line arguments when you run your program. Therefore the makefile has nothing to do with passing command line arguments. If you want to avoid passing command line arguments to the program altogether, you need to change the program, you cannot fix it in the makefile.

Comment: Also please do not post images of code. They are not helpful.

Comment: Okay, so can I pass command line arguments when using a makefile, how should I proceed, as I must use a command line argument to pass the file name?

Comment: "passing command line arguments" to your program when you run it has nothing at all do with your makefile, because your makefile doesn't **run** your program, your makefile **builds** your program.  Once make has finished building your program based on the makefile, you can run it from your shell prompt by typing `./book` and if you want to pass an argument `somearg` to it, you'd run `./book somearg`

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, thank you, I was not understanding how everything connects, the makefile was correct, I just did not know how to use it, thank you!